# How to add subforms to a form in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, subforms

i have two little questions to you:
How to add several subforms to a form in C# like on the pictures below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ag1WD.jpg]
[Cascade]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzBGH.jpg]
[Tile]

And the second one is how to manage their position(Cascade, Tile, etc.).
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Ick.  Use tabs; your pictured style is so 90's

Comment: You have to use [Multiple Document Interface (MDI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984329(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: @robert-harvey, that was a task at my university, and now I use tabs when I need;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [Multiple Document Interface (MDI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyhh2e7e.aspx) form but, as Robert Harvey mentioned in a comment, there's probably a better way to build your UI.

To layout the child forms you will use the [LayoutMdi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fhk181.aspx) method of the parent.

Answer (score 3):

It's called MDI (Multiple Document Interface). To do that, you need to change the `IsMdiContainer` property of the MainForm to `true`. And then you need to change the `MdiParent` property of the child Forms to your MainForm instance.

You can have a method in your MainForm class like:

```
public void MakeChildForm(Form childForm)
{
    childForm.MdiParent = this;
}
```